# Google Maps / Assets / Grid

Tags: assets, grid, google-maps-for-ee

I'm attempting to insert an Assets field, Grid data along with some other text input fields into a Info Box in a Store Locator page. My code is as follows:

```
{exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" sort="asc" parse="inward" cache_post="false"}
{if has_searched}
    {results}
        {exp:gmap:marker
            id="map1"
            title="{title}"
            address="{locations_address1} {locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}"
            extend_bounds="false"
            open_windows="false"
            show_one_window="true"
            clustering="true"
            duplicate_markers="false"
        }
                <div class="locations">
                    {if locations_image}{locations_image}<img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='{locations_image:url}' url_only='yes' width='708' height='396' crop='yes|center,center'}" alt="{alt_text}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/locations_image}{/if}
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="title">{title}</div>
                        <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
                        <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
                        <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
                        {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
                        {/locations_hours}</p>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- end locations -->
        {/exp:gmap:marker}
    {/results}
{if:else}
<div id="locations_wrapper">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channel}" status="not closed" sort="desc" orderby="date" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"}<div class="locations {switch='pull-left|pull-right'}">
        {if locations_image}{locations_image}<img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='{url}' url_only='yes' width='708' height='396' crop='yes|center,center'}" alt="{alt_text}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/locations_image}{/if}
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">{count}. {title}</div>
            {categories}{if category_url_title == 'john-atencio-store'}<div class="store_type">{category_name}</div>{/if}{/categories}
            <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
            <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
            <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
            {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
            {/locations_hours}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div><!-- end locations -->
    {switch='|<div class="clearfix"></div>'}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div><!-- end locations_wrapper -->
{/if}

{if no_results}
    <h2>No locations found, try another search.</h2>
{/if}
{/exp:gmap:results}
```

What's strange is that my index page works fine with the Assets and Grid. It's just the items in the `{if has_searched}{results}...{/results}{if:else}` items aren't parsing. The standard fields are working but anything that needs a tag pair to render doesn't.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic or it could be a bug too! :) Isn't everything a bug if you can't figure something out :)?

Thanks for the help on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just had some loops in the wrong place:

```
{exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" parse="inward" sort="asc" cache_post="false"}
{if has_searched}<div id="locations_wrapper">
    {results}
        {exp:gmap:marker
            id="map1"
            title="{title}"
            address="{locations_address1} {locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}"
            extend_bounds="false"
            open_windows="false"
            show_one_window="true"
            clustering="true"
            duplicate_markers="false"
        }
        {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channel}" limit="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" orderby="date" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"}
            <div class="locations">
                {if locations_image}<img src="{locations_image:url}" alt="{locations_image:alt_tag}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/if}
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">{title}</div>
                    <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
                    <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
                    <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
                    {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
                    {/locations_hours}</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end locations -->
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/exp:gmap:marker}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channel}" parse="inward" limit="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" orderby="date" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"}
            <div class="locations pull-left">
                {if locations_image}<img src="{locations_image:url}" alt="{locations_image:alt_tag}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/if}
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">{title}</div>
                    {categories}{if category_url_title == 'john-atencio-store'}<div class="store_type">{category_name}</div>{/if}{/categories}
                    <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
                    <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
                    <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
                    {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
                    {/locations_hours}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!-- end locations -->
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/results}
</div><!-- end locations_wrapper -->{if:else}
        <div id="locations_wrapper">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channel}" status="not closed" sort="desc" orderby="date" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no"}
        {exp:gmap:marker
            id="map1"
            title="{title}"
            address="{locations_address1} {locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}"
            extend_bounds="false"
            open_windows="false"
            show_one_window="true"
            clustering="true"
            duplicate_markers="false"
        }
        <div class="locations">
            {if locations_image}{locations_image}<img src="{url}" alt="{title}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/locations_image}{/if}
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">{title}</div>
                <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
                <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
                <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
                {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
                {/locations_hours}</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end locations -->
        {/exp:gmap:marker}
            <div class="locations {switch='pull-left|pull-right'}">
                {if locations_image}{locations_image}<img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='{url}' url_only='yes' width='708' height='396' crop='yes|center,center'}" alt="{alt_text}" class="img-responsive pull-left" />{/locations_image}{/if}
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="title">{absolute_count}. {title}</div>
                    {categories}{if category_url_title == 'john-atencio-store'}<div class="store_type">{category_name}</div>{/if}{/categories}
                    <p class="address">{locations_address1},{if locations_address2}<br />{locations_address2}{/if}<br />{locations_city}, {locations_state} {locations_zip}</p>
                    <p class="locations_phone"><strong>Phone:</strong> {locations_phone}</p>
                    <p class="hours"><strong>Store Hours:</strong><br />
                    {locations_hours backspace="6"}<span class="days">{locations_hours:day}</span> <span class="hours">{locations_hours:time}</span><br />
                    {/locations_hours}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!-- end locations -->
            {switch='|<div class="clearfix"></div>'}
    {/exp:channel:entries}</div><!-- end locations_wrapper -->
{/if}

{if no_results}
    <h2>No locations found, try another search.</h2>
{/if}
{/exp:gmap:results}
```